# PyQtGraph with PySide producing tiny, squashed graphs (including the example code)

Tags: python, pyside, pyqtgraph

I am running Python 3.3 with PySide 1.2.2 and PyQtGraph 0.9.8.

The problem I am having is that every graph I try and produce returns an obviously incorrect result.

This is the graph I get when I run the basic plotting example that is packaged with PyQtGraph:

[image: Here]

Rather than what I am supposed to get:
[image: Here]
<sub>(source: [pyqtgraph.org](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/images/plotting.png))</sub>

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think I have seen something like this before.. Have you changed any of the DPI settings in windows or through your graphics driver? Do let us know if you determine the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A description of the problem and solution could be found here: [pyqtgraph Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/pyqtgraph/PySide$20Problem/pyqtgraph/J6Hz0IO8fK4/dneZjxw61Y0J)

The problem is caused by a faulty binary installation file from  Christoph Gohlke's otherwise excellent binary download page ([Link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)).

The solution is to instead use pip:

> pip install PySide

Answer (score 0):

The issue is also found in the conda packge for PySide. See the discussion at https://github.com/conda-forge/pyside-feedstock/issues/15.

It can be fixed with pip and should also be fixed on the conda forge channel soon.