# PyQtGraph not working after move from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyside, pyqtgraph

I've needed to move from 32bit to 64bit Python, and have run into a problem with pyqtgraph plotting.

Even the simplest examples are displaying the same behaviour (SimplePlot.py for instance, from the examples folder)

Running SimplePlot.py shows the window, but the window is empty except for a squiggle in the top left, which I  am guessing is the plot.. If I left click inside the window and pan it, the plot shows with a sensible size, though still with no axes or titles.
Right clicking brings up the menu as expected, but any changes are not visible until i close the menu and pan the plot again. The examples work fine when run within a 32bit environment...

I'm using an anaconda environment (Python 2.7.12) with the following packages installed:

pyqtgraph 0.910
PySide 1.2.4
numpy 1.11.1
scipy 0.18.0
cython 0.24.1

All packages (including pyqtgraph) were installed with pip.
No exceptions or errors are shown when I see these issues.

Has anyone seen this before? 
Please note: I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520108/pyqtgraph-with-pyside-producing-tiny-squashed-graphs-including-the-example-cod), and tried the solution. It didn't alter the behaviour in my case

Thanks for any help!

[image: This is before I pan the plot]
[image: This is after I pan the plot]

Comment: Is there a reason you are using PySide over PyQt? I suspect there aren't problems with PyQt.

Comment: The licenses are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is also found in the conda packge for PySide. See the discussion at https://github.com/conda-forge/pyside-feedstock/issues/15.

It can be fixed with pip and should also be fixed on the conda forge channel soon.

Our quickfix for conda is a custom built package based on the offical (and working) binaries from the Qt Download website at https://download.qt.io/official_releases/pyside/